# Auto fulfil backorders when supplier orders arrives to warehouse on ACUMATICA ERP

Tags: acumatica, erp, fulfillment

we just had Acumatica ERP implemented in our company by a third-party consultant (CloudInfo) in México but they and us missed something I honestly didn’t see it was missing in Acumatica as far as we understand, and its something we had in Netsuite and other ERP’s we used before.

When a supplier arrives to the physical location, we confirm the fulfillment to the warehouse so product is available to complete orders manually but not automatic. Sales people needs to enter each order and evaluate each line to complete the order. But there are 2 mayor problems as it is on our case:

1. There is a chronological order in which the orders where place, so having orders to be fulfill manually the older orders might not get complete as it’s in the hands of sale rep actions without any control.
2. There are hundreds of orders for each sales representative so having them to manually enter the

So, it’s almost impossible to consider a manual complete of each order line. We need a process to AUTO complete orders that where waiting for product to be available and notify the sales rep so they schedule logistics.

As we don’t have that process, we also need a report to know orders that can be potentially complete so they know witch orders over probably 1,000 orders and push with workflow.

Is there any consultant that has work this before so we don’t have to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I think this question is off topic for stackoverflow as its not a programming question related to Acumatica. It sounds like a functionality/gap question in the software.

Comment: your are right @Brendan. are I see from your profile you work around Acumatica. Where is the best place / forum to post this type of questions?

Comment: That is a good question - not sure about general functionality questions. Maybe open up a case with Acumatica or review/post to https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas . You could also google to find some Acumatica blogs to ask some questions there too. Not much help here sorry.